# VSS back to back like vPC back to back

Tags: spanning-tree, vpc, vss, cisco-4500

I know vPC back to back to avoid spanning tree between two pairs of Nexus.

But I've two 4500 pairs and I need to connect them. Is there a way to do something similar to the vPC back to back to don't use spanning tree?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure VSS on Cisco 4500E, The Cisco Virtual Switching System is a clustering technology that pools two Cisco Catalyst 4500-E Series Switches with Cisco Catalyst Supervisor Engine 7-E or 7-LE or two Catalyst 4500-X Series Switches into a single virtual switch. In a VSS, the data plane of both clustered switches is active at the same time in both chassis. VSS members are connected by virtual switch links (VSLs) using standard Gigabit or 10 Gigabit Ethernet connections between the VSS members. VSLs can carry regular user traffic in addition to the control plane communication between the VSS members.
you could find more info on the below link: 
[Virtual switching system (VSS) Configuration For Cisco 4500 series switches](https://supportforums.cisco.com/document/124626/virtual-switching-system-vss-configuration-cisco-4500-series-switches)

Comment: Sorry but you don't answer to the question. I'm trying to know how to connect 2 PAIRS of VSS 4500. You're telling me how to configure two SWITCHES for VSS

Answer (score 1):

If you configured each pair of 4500s as a VSS, then linked them together with an active/LACP port channel you could achieve an all active topology (which is what I assume you are looking for).

You would need to ensure that one port from each PortChannel is assigned to each VSS member.

Comment: If I have one port-channel between each switch of the vss pairs, I can have an all active topology? How's that?

Comment: @Jey10: Using Multichassis Etherchannel http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/solutions/Enterprise/Campus/VSS30dg/campusVSS_DG/VSS-dg_ch3.html

Comment: yeah I'm just asking if I can make work MEC like vPC back to back

Comment: Yes it will work